# Is it a bad idea to rescale time scale for batch data?

Tags: time-series

I have data from an industrial batch process.The problem is that the batches duration are not always the same. 
To illustrate the issue, here is a simple example for illustration only:
consider two sequences  A and B .

A: t 1   2      3   4    5

y 0.1 0.2 0.05 0.01   0.2

B: t: 1   2    3    4

y 0.1 0.35 0.4  0.199

My coworker insists on  changing the time scale by multiplying A's time axis  by 4/5 but my guts tell me that this is not a good idea specially when you see that advanced algorithms exist to deal with this kind of problems such as  [Dynamic Time Warping](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dynamic_time_warping).

Can somebody please elaborate more on the pros and cons of such a basic technique whith if possible mathematical proof?

Answer (score 1):

You did not give enough context to answer this question.

Consider the situations below, which are text analogues of this

1)

ccaattnniipp
catnip

You should rescale the shorter pattern to be the same length, you don’t need DTW.

2)
ccaattnniipppppppp
caaaaaaaaatttnippp

They are already the same length, but you DO need DTW

3)

ccaattnniipp
caaaatnip

They are different lengths, but rescaling is not enough, you need to (also) do DTW.

Which world are you in? I have seen all three in the oil and gas space. To understand DTW, read [a]

eamonn

[a] http://www.cs.unm.edu/~mueen/DTW.pdf